# Convert csv file to Pipe delimited file in Talend

Tags: pipe, talend

I am using Talend and the schema changes for an input file (csv) that I want to convert to pipe delimited.  The csv file has double quote (") text qualifier and within the quotes I don't want the comma to be a pipe.  A tReplace replaces every comma.  Basically I need the following lines 
123,456,PO Box 124

12,42,"12 Main, NY"

"5,065",342,"Las Vegas, NV"

to be

123|456|PO Box 124

12|42|12 Main, NY

5,065|342|Las Vegas, NV

Thanks ahead of time for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have the following settings configured for your tFileInputDelimited -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, my schmea changes.  I was thinking I do a tInputFullRow.  I then need to find a way to get the commas to Pipes but not within the quotes and then I can do a tOutputFileDelimted as one file could have 4 columns, the next could have 3 columns.